# How Can I Quickly Create Embossed Text in the Style of a Label Maker

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, text-object

**Some background:**

- I'm working on a big project, modelling a car, and I'm currently creating the cockpit
- The car is a race-car, and the instruments and switches on the dashboard are all labeled blue and white embossed labels, a picture for reference:
  [image: Toytota Celica GTO Cockpit]

**What I need Help With**

- I need help finding a quick and resource friendly way to create all of the labels
- I'd like the textures on a flat object that looks like it has texture using normal maps

**My Current Workflow**

- Create text, convert to a mesh, planar dissolve unnecessary vertices, extrude the text, bevel the edges, joining it with a plane, use some mask tools to add dust and damage, the bake the diffuse, normal, and roughness maps to a flat plane.

Currently I feel like there should be a simpler way to do this, specifically the baking. If I only had to do this for one object it wouldn't be that big of a deal, but there are like 25 labels on this dashboard, all with different text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need extra geometry, just use an image as a bump map to fake the relief. This will allow you to keep the vertex count low, as all you need is a simple plane.

[image]

Or you can use the image as displacement if you need real geometry.

[image]

Note that, in order to get good results, you need a lot of subdivisions.

Of course you will need the correct **dymo** font to create the texture:

[https://www.fonts4free.net/dymo-font.html#:~:text=Dymo's%20embossing%20font%20is%20now,Type%20Studio%2C%20exclusively%20for%20Dymo.&text=Dymo%20font%20contains%20230%20defined%20characters%20and%20116%20unique%20glyphs](https://www.fonts4free.net/dymo-font.html#:%7E:text=Dymo%27s%20embossing%20font%20is%20now,Type%20Studio%2C%20exclusively%20for%20Dymo.&text=Dymo%20font%20contains%20230%20defined%20characters%20and%20116%20unique%20glyphs).

Comment: What a great result.. Waves of nostalgia :) I got a Mini-Dymo for my 10th birthday in 1970. My grandfather took it apart, because he wanted to figure out how it worked. He never managed to put it back together. Runs in the family.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for your help!